# iphone development: how to put a UIView over UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

In my app I use storyboard. One of my elements in the storyboard is a UITableViewController. So it has a tableview inside of it.

My question is how can I put a UIView over this tableview. It is gonna be hidden and I want to make it visible when a tableviewcell in the tableview is pressed. Is that possible? How can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand the last part - the view will hide the table, but the user will select a cell to dismiss it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution is use normal view controller (UIViewController) in StoryBoard. Your controller will need to implement two protocols (UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate) and you will need add UITablewView in the view controller's view.

In this case in interface builder you will be able to put any view in the view controller's view (can put it above table view).

Comment: I also think it is the best way since I can also see the view in storyboard. Otherwise, I had to make everything by coding for the UIView. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use tableHeaderView property.

Returns accessory view that is displayed above the table.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *tableHeaderView
```

The table header view is different from a section header.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your view to be hidden/shown on top of table view is topView, declared as a global variable.
Declare topView in .h as

```
 UIView *topView;
```

Now Lets assume that you have the UITableViewController object as tableViewController then, initialize the topView in viewDidLoad of tableViewController class

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
         topView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:yourNeededFrameSize];
         [self.tableView addSubview:topView];//tableView is a property for UITableViewController inherited class 
         topView.hidden=YES;//Hide it initially for the first time. 
}
```

assuming that you have the UITableViewDelegate methods implemented here is what you will do in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(topView.isHidden==YES)
    {
        topView.hidden=NO;
    }
    else
    {
        topView.hidden=NO;
    }

}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: In your example `topView` would be an ivar not a global variable. You have also forgotten to call `[super viewDidLoad];`

Answer (score 0):

you can also get view into front.

```
[view bringsubviewtofront];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to add a loading indicator on top of my UITableViewController. To solve this, I added my UIView as a subview of the window. That solved the problem. This is how I did it.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
            [super viewDidLoad];
            //get the app delegate
            XYAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

            //define the position of the rect based on the screen bounds
            CGRect loadingViewRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2, 50, 50);
            //create the custom view. The custom view is a property of the VIewController
            self.loadingView = [[XYLoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:loadingViewRect];
            //use the delegate's window object to add the custom view on top of the view controller
            [delegate.window addSubview: loadingView]; 
        }
```